# What is the meaning of "aslamwalequm"?

Tags: arabic, greetings

If someone (non believer) wishes you with aslamwalequm instead of asalaamo alaiqum. Is it by intention or merely a mis-pronunciation? Is it death upon you or stones upon you or nay other meaning since a non-believer is targeting me with this phrase? What will be the reply to him?

Comment: As much as I know, the best reply for bad salutation is saying: Alaikum. Actually it means whatever you are saying, be for you.

Comment: Of course I assume God will bless you with a good effect in case of making mistake. Actually I reckon it would be Ok if he says it unintentionally. / Meanwhile, almost, I can remember a similar story which sb told the Prophet Saam-alaikum (I think a non-Muslim), then the Prophet replied him: alaikum (namely: to you, whatever you say)

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I will say alaikum to him when he greets me now

Comment: yeah, that's the best way. to be honest I am not sure regarding the intention of the Prophet that he means :  .. to you,  but almost I am sure in a si,milar matter that : the Prophet replied him(them) : Wa alaik (and to you). Good luck mate.

Comment: The person sends me a message on whatsapp typing aslamwalequm. So I assume it is not a typo and it is does intentionally. So should I type alaikum or Wa alaik. Could a muslim do a typo error. Please assist

Comment: The best answer for non believer is wailikum

Answer (score 2):

```
                  In the name of Allah, the compassionate, the merciful
```

> What is the meaning of aslamwalequm? … What will be the reply to him?

The mentioned phrase “aslamwalequm” seems to be the incomplete or wrong shape of ASsalamo-Alaikum. And apparently a miss-pronunciation as you said. Hence, you’d better inform him concerning his wrong if he says it unintentionally.

---

Let’s give you a related example which can be constructive and helpful for you. It is narrated that:

> Munafiqs (or Jews according to another narration) were saying
>   Saam-Alaik to the apostle of Allah (peace be upon him and his family).
>   And they would curse him by that. … Afterwards the following verse
>   came down (revelation):
>
> و اذا جاوك حيوك بما لم يحيك به اللّه مجادله:8 /

So, it is quoted that:

> … some Jew entered and told the Prophet degradingly “Saam Alaik”
>   (down or death to you) although it has a similar form to
>   Assalam-o-Alaik. But the apostle of Allah dignified and politely
>   replied him: Wa Alaik. (Of course didn’t say Saam Alaik, haply solely
>   he replied “Wa Alaik”)

Accordingly, you’d better tell him Wa alaik (especially if you assume or sure that he had a bad intention by saying that).

---

As another narration which could be helpful and perhaps related to some extent:

> It is quoted that the apostle of Allah (peace be upon him and his
>   family) said: do not reply the person who start speaking without
>   greeting Salam (without Saying Assalam-o-alaik... at first)
>
> According to a hadith: Somebody came to Imam Hussain (a.s.)
>   and told him كيف انت عافاك الله without saying Salam (Assalam-o-Alaik)
>   at first.  Imam Hussain told him: (السلام قبل الكلام عافاك الله)
>   (saying Salam has priority on talking …)

---

**Reference**:

- [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread28016.html)

Comment: The person sends me a message on whatsapp typing aslamwalequm. So I assume it is not a typo and it is does intentionally. So should I type alaikum or Wa alaik. Could a muslim do a typo error. Please assist

Comment: Firstly, I myself try to be an optimist person and look at the issues optimistically. Secondly he could wrote it wrongly as a brief phrase. Thirdly in pessimistic position: you can write: Wa Alaik (As Prophet Muhammad said it as our pattern (pattern of the life).

Comment: regarding Alaikum, I can state that: it can be used in two ways: 1: in plural form (when there are more than one (or 2) person 2: it is used as a respected form in some countries (by using plural form for someone, therefore you'd better avoid using "Alaikum" for the person who can have negative intention... Finally as you wish. Good luck dear mate.

Answer (score 1):

> "aslamwalequm"

has nothing harmful inside it. It is just the way the non-Muslim is able to say the phrase. So it should be treated as perfectly fine.

However,

> "as-saam alaykum"

is the form which contains harm, "as-saam" means poison or death. So, the letter **laam** "l" means all the difference here.